# reformat file contents in a specific way

Tags: linux, bash, awk

Hi I have the following file

```
+--------------------------+-----------------------+-----------------------+- +
|         col_name         |       data_type       |        comment        |
+--------------------------+-----------------------+-----------------------+--+
| id                       | string                |                       |
| name                     | string                |                       |
| filename                 | string                |                       |
| loaddate                 | string                |                       |
| recordid                 | string                |                       |
|                          | NULL                  | NULL                  |
| # Partition Information  | NULL                  | NULL                  |
| # col_name               | data_type             | comment               |
|                          | NULL                  | NULL                  |
| fname                    | string                |                       |
+--------------------------+-----------------------+-----------------------+--+
```

I would like to create this output

```
id,name,filename,loaddate,recordid
```

Basically column names with comma separated list except the header, footer and partition info.

Used two awk s and a paste to achieve the desired output and used paste to create one line, used a temp file.

```
awk 'NR>3 {l[NR] = $0} END {for (i=1; i<=NR-3; i++) print l[i]}' g.txt > t.t
awk '{if (substr($2,3,1) != "") print $2}' t.t | paste -s -d ,
```

the question is how can I do this in one line of command?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do it:

```
awk 'NR>3 && NR<9 {if (substr($2,1,1) != "") {if(length(a) == 0) {a=$2} else {a=a","$2}}} END {print a}' a='' g.txt
```

Output is:

```
id,name,filename,loaddate,recordid
```

Comment: it didn't remove the last column, which has the partition info, the result is "id,name,filename,load date,recorded,name"   the desired output is  "id,name,filename,loaddate,recordid"

Comment: hmm... missed that part of your requirements - updated ;)

Comment: thanks again!. what's the purpose of a='' at the end?

Comment: it initialises the variable - not explicitly required though (just good practice).

Comment: I see... makes sense